# How do I type this math problem in Python?

Tags: python

[image]

Shouldn't it be:

```
ratio = (1 + 5**(1/2))/2
```

Or are my parenthesis in the wrong places here?

Details: This is from an online Python course a friend is taking. She needed help because it kept saying the answer is wrong. I gave her what I posted above (even though I'm not familiar with Python) but it's still not saying it's correct. Who knows why, maybe the test question is messed up.

Comment: That looks right to me. Are you sure that it's producing the incorrect value?

Comment: Is this like an online course where they check your results? Perhaps they want math.sqrt?

Comment: Yes, it's an online course a friend is taking. She needed help because it kept saying the answer is wrong. I gave her what I posted above (even though I'm not familiar with Python) but it's still not saying it's correct. Who knows why, maybe the test question is messed up.

Comment: Did you try using `math.sqrt` as suggested below? It really shouldn't matter, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: In Python 3 it's right. In Python 2 you would want to divide by 2.0 instead of 2 (in both places) to give float division instead of int division.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct.
If you want a more direct method you can import the `square root` function from math:

```
import math

ratio = (1 + math.sqrt(5))/2
```

But it will give you the same answer:

```
>>> ratio
1.618033988749895
```